# Node.js POST API and parsing of request body

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, node.js, rest

being a Node newbie, I seem to be struggling with some very basic steps. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Essentially, I'm trying to send an input from an iOS (Objective-C) client to a Node.js server, but somehow not able to parse the http message body. In fact the data being posted from the client is not even appearing in the request if I log the same in the POST API on the server. I can confirm the endpoints are correct since other logs are getting printed... Here's my iOS and Node code - seems to be pretty straightforward...

Appreciate your inputs...

iOS code:

```
- (IBAction)sendUsername:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MYURL:PORT/registerUser"]];

    NSDictionary *sentData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"socool", @"username", nil];
    NSError *theError = nil;
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sentData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&theError];

    [postRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [postRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    // Have tried with both - initWithRequest and with sendSyncRequest - both dont show the req.body on the server...

    // NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];

    NSError *returnedError = nil;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = [[NSURLResponse alloc] init];
    NSData *dataResponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&returnedError];  
}
```

Node.js code:

```
app.post('/registerUser', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Request to register new user received"); // This gets printed successfully...    

    body = [];
    body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();           

    console.log("Targeted output is: ", req.body.username); // req.body itself keeps coming as undefined.
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using ExpressJS. If that's the case, prior to setting up your route with app.post, did you specify a bodyParser?

Take a look at this: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Specifically, the 'req.body' section.

Express relies upon a middleware that is going to intercept the request, parse it, and then fill req.body with it.

Comment: Ughh... quite what happens when one doesn't copy code without understanding! Thanks @Chazzu